# How to change color of AccuracyCircle in Skobblers (now Scout) SKMaps for iOS

Tags: skmaps

I'm using SKMaps in my app and I managed to change the color of the current position indicator (default is blue) by changing the png files in the SKMaps.bundle. Now I would like the color of the AccuracyCircle to match with the color of my custom position indicator. It looks like the accuracy circle is code created (so not a png file) in the .m file (which I don't have as it's SKMaps.framework) and there doesn't seem to be a setting of any kind to change the color. Does anyone know a way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [orientationIndicatorType](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.3.0/Classes/SKMapSettings.html#//api/name/orientationIndicatorType) property from the SKMapSettings:

```
/** The orientation indicator type, used when SKMapFollowerModePositionPlusHeading follower is active. If SKOrientationIndicatorCustomImage is set, the "heading.png" image file from the style's resources will be used. 
 */ 
@property(nonatomic, assign) SKOrientationIndicatorType orientationIndicatorType;
```

Comment: Thanks Ando. I looked into it. At first it seemed like a good solution but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. The accuracy circle changes size when accuracy changes, but the heading image does not. Furthermore it has an unwanted side effect for my case. I was using the SKMapFollowerModePosition and when I change this to SKMapFollowerModePostionPlusHeading the map (logically) starts turning to keep North Up, which is something I don't want.

Comment: I was playing around with positionerService.gpsAccuracyLevel with the thought to make a custom accuracy circle, however the gpsAccuracy level does not seem to be in line the built-in accuracyCircle. I.e. the built-in accuracyCircle is not showing (which I think means accuracy is really good), but positionerService.gpsAccuracyLevel still indicates SKGPSAccuracyLevel.Bad.